# SKProduct localizedDescription in different languages

Tags: ios6, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have in `app purchase` in my `app`. I am testing a thai language device with a test account that is in the thai store. I have both English and thai in app purchase titles and descriptions.

`SKProductsResponse (product details[localizedDescription, localizedTitle] of SKProduct)`always returning in English.

What am I doing wrong?

My Test Device  setup in the Thailand store with Thai as the language, but product details returning in english, i want to show user in `thai format` .

how it is possible, i tried so many way but i didn't find any solution till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a test user account on iTunes Connect, and set it's iTune Store to Thailand. Then sign out your apple id from your device, but don't sign in with your test user account here. When you start purchasing your product, iTune account dialog will prompt you to sign in your Apple ID. After you sign in with your test account here, you should see the product details in Thai.

You can get more information in detail from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155802/testing-in-app-purchases-for-multilanguage/9349427#9349427)